# Angular Universal - Multiple NetworkError

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-httpclient

When I implemented angular universal with ng add @nguniversal/express-engine, i saw about 20 errors of this...

```
ERROR NetworkError
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:83582:19)
    at Observable._subscribe (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:173460:17)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:65954:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:65940:22)
    at DoOperator.call (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:182857:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:65935:31)
    at scheduleTask (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:58312:32)
    at Observable._subscribe (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:58350:13)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:65954:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Todor\Desktop\flatoro ssr\Flatoro-frontend\dist\Flatoro-frontend\server\main.js:65940:22)
```

I have pretty large application so it's very difficult to debug. On web app almost everything works great just I have problem on refresh, if it's not base url it's just continue pending...I tested GUI, every function works, every api request works but why i'm getting these errors ?

I have socket.io-client where I added checking for platform...

```
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      this.socket = io('https://localhost:4200', {
        transports: ['websocket'],
      });
    }
```

For authentification i'm using httponly secure cookies and i have interceptor which is adding withCredentials on every request, i thought that can be a problem but when i removed that everything stays the same..

```
   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authReq = request.clone({
          withCredentials: true
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);
      ;
  }
```

I'm using absoulute path to api, this is example of my service..

```
  url = environment.url;

   getMyReviews(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url + '/users/getMyReviews');
  }
```

And I'm using ngrx, I really don't have idea what can causing these problems.

Comment: Maybe a proxy setting. In your interceptor add a console.log with request details before sending it, to try to identify which request is causing the issue

Comment: That's right man, assets are problem, he is showing error on every asset. I'm adding assets like this <img src="../../../assets/img.jpg">.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm using angular-svg-icon library and i didn't setup that for Universal. You saved my day ! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. But interceptor should not intercept assets requests, since they are not xhr requests... how did you figure it out?

Comment: Maybe for server side they are, i have error interceptor ``` @Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _injector: Injector) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(event => {}, err => {
        console.log(err);
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 404) {
            console.log(err);
              const router = this._injector.get(Router);
              router.navigate(['/404']);
          }
      }));
  }
}```

Comment: oh ok, thanks for letting me know